# Dreamweaver CS4 incredibly slow when I type a double quote or parentheses

Tags: php, dreamweaver, cs4

Not really a code question I know, but I recently upgraded to Dreamweaver CS4 and every time I type a double quote or parentheses in code view (the code's in PHP) Dreamweaver sort of freezes up for a few second and I get the Mac pinwheel thing.  My guess is Dreamweaver's trying to do some sort of validation or check or maybe is just analyzing how to color the code, but whatever it's doing, it takes forever and is really annoying when I'm right in the middle of typing out code.

The longer the file is, the longer it takes.  It's really only noticeable if the file is over 5000 lines or so and I know it's probably not a 'best practice' thing to have files with code over 5000 lines, but I have some which are nearly 20,000 and Dreamweaver seems to nearly crash every time I type a double quote or parentheses.

CS3 worked fine and I don't think it's my computer (iMac with 2.93 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4 GB of memory). Anyway, my question is does any body know if there's anything I can do to fix this (short of breaking up all my large files)?  Maybe there's some validation or setting I can turn off in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Mac, my computer is more worse than you (2.7GHz Core2Duo 2GB Memory). but dreamweaver CS4 in my PC run smootlhy or Maybe some issue adobe product for Mac.

Anyway than that. i recommended you use `macpadd++` or maybe `netbeans` for hardcoding, they also free.